# Exchange 2019 Migration - Mailbox Migrations

Tags: migration, exchange-2013, exchange-2019

We're migrating from 2013 to 2019 and so far everything is going well.  I've moved a good set of our user mailboxes with no issues and connectivity, mail flow, etc.

What I keep running into is these hidden arbitration mailboxes that I had no clue existed that need to be migrated and this got me thinking about what else I need to migrate before decommissioning our 2013 instance.

Currently, I'm aware of migrating: User, Room Resource, Shared Mailboxes.  Public Folders.

Is there a comprehensive list of what needs to migrated and what doesn't?  Is there command I should be running right before our 2013 instance is uninstalled and decommissioned to catch these things and migrate them?

I've been scouring the internet to try to find anything but most articles just simply say move all your mailboxes and public folders, turn off 2013 for a week.  Then turn it back on if there are no issues and run the uninstaller to remove 2013 from the domain appropriately.

Comment: https://www.alitajran.com/move-arbitration-mailboxes-in-exchange-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move arbitration mailboxes first, before you move user mailboxes.

Here is a similar case you could refer to: [When to Move arbitration mailboxes ?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/400042/when-to-move-arbitration-mailboxes)

Also, do you use [Exchange Deployment Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/exchange-deployment-assistant?view=exchserver-2019) to help with mailbox migration? If not, you can refer to it: [On-Premise Exchange Deployment Guide](https://setup.microsoft.com/exchange/deployment-assistant)

Comment: I concur with this advice and the first link makes it clear, especially the link inside that to Rhoderick Milne's blog.  Also, it's incredibly easy to move the arbitration mailboxes `get-mailbox -arbitration | new-moverequest -targetdatabase <NewDB>` - just get it done in one hit.

Comment: Just to clarify further, the arbitration mailbox move can and should be done now, prior to decommissioning any legacy databases/servers.

Answer (score 0):

It has been about 4 years since I went from 2010 -> 2016 -> 2019, but I don't THINK the arbitration mailboxes are required to be migrated. That said if you do need to move them Exchange 2013 has 5 arbitration mailboxes and there's even more in 2019. You can use `Get-Mailbox -Arbitration` to see all of them.

From what I recall of my migration I hit the same mailboxes you did and didn't have any issues. I also used this guide which was very helpful, https://practical365.com/migrating-exchange-server-2016/.

Comment: You might get away with this if you don't have any of the moderation/arbitration features enabled on your mailboxes, but it's really not good practice. System/arbitration mailboxes should be dealt with first.